# OWA marks messages as unread on deletion

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

I'm using OWA in FF 65, with Exchange 2016(?) as a backend.

Whenever I delete a message, it shows up in the deleted folder as a new message.  This screws up my notifier for unread messages, making it very difficult to know when I have new mail.

I've searched but not been able to find a solution.  I've tried setting the option "Mark the item displayed in the reading pane as read" at 0 seconds, but even with the email already marked as read it still shows up as unread in deleted items :(

Comment: If you also have this account configured in Outlook for Office 365, you can go to  File > Options > Mail. Look for the “Other” section and check the box next to “Mark messages as read when deleted”.

Comment: Thanks @YukiSun!  I actually didn't have a desktop client until yesterday :)  I tried your suggestion, but there is [no such option on my Outlook 2016](https://imgur.com/a/Zh4LI6O)